# Is it necessary to keep favicon and apple icons at site root?

Tags: html, web

Is it necessary to keep favicon and apple icons at site root?

```
/favicon.ico
/apple-touch-icon.png
```

or it can be

```
/favicons/favicon.ico
/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the icon file wherever you want and name it whatever you want.

But then you need to use a link tag to point to it:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicons/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
```

If it is named `favicon.ico` and is on the root, most browsers will pick it up automatically.

For the mobile apple platforms to pick it up automatically, it needs to be named `apple-touch-icon.png` and be placed in the root as well.

Comment: can we also use external favicon?

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas - Yes, the `href` attribute takes any valid URI.

Answer (score 1):

It can be where ever you want... By default, I believe browsers, or Safari at least, look in your root if you haven't' defined a location. But like I said, it can be where ever.